# facebook graph and access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

when I do a get request to

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[userid]
```

with the `access_token` i get all the basic info

but when I do

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me
```

with the same token i get an error `message: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user`

I have tried to under stand what can cause that.
I even tried to token that comes with the signed request

I'm on classic asp, with JSON library, I want the auto to be server side if possible. the `FB.api("/me"` is working but it is not what i really want to achive

Comment: your issue is same here bro

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342266/an-active-access-token-must-be-used-to-query-information-about-the-current-user

Comment: does not help me, i'm on ASP not PHP

Comment: user not logged in with server side portion of your app.  You say the javacript sdk works, they are logged in there.  The server side portion must also log in user if you are going to use the server side api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure you don´t have a user access token. Did you login the user? Of course you get the public data of every user with your first link, even without any access token. You can even put it directly in the browser and will get results. But for "/me" you have to authorize the user to your app.

See here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/

It is the same problem as in the other thread for sure, just a different Programming language.
Remember: If the user did not accept at least the basic permissions in a dialog or redirect, he is not logged in and you will never know anything about him in the app (except for some specifics in tab apps, like language, like-status and stuff).